# Git push successfully pushes all folders but one

Tags: android, git

I have an Android Studio app that is using Volley to handle get requests.  When I push the project to GitHub, I get an error:  Push partially failed
/home/filepath: pushed 1 commit to origin/mybranch volley: failed with error: fatal: remote error:

Every other file pushes successfully.  Only the Volley folder fails.

Anyone have any ideas on why this happens?  Thanks.

Comment: is it possible that you are trying to push it on the volley's repository ?

Comment: That was the problem.  I reset the remote to my repository. Now my pushes are just rejected.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have much reputation to answer this in comments but i think its the difference branch issue with the repository. Are you sure you are pushing it on the same branch? try git push origin master.